# What is "blk_update_request" in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, crash-reports, ubuntu-server

Sometimes my ubuntu crashs with error:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error at, dev sda, sector ...
```

**What does it mean ?**

Edit: I have **SSD** hard drive

Answer (score 1):

That usually means your drive is dying. Use `smartctl` to assess the damage and save the important data if/while you still can.